# problems with running MAMP /"Please check your configuration permissions and write rights and try again."

Tags: mamp

everyone. I downloaded MAMP on my Windows and something went wrong. I got this errors: "MAMP could not create configuration files for PHP version. Please check your configuration permissions and write rights and try again. MAMP will exit now"

"MAMP has detected errors in configuration files. Please check logs for more details.."

nothing is in logs folder

Do u have any ideas?

i checked logs folder and tried to type in the terminal with instruction from this syte :https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/mamp-not-starting/

it didnt help me

Answer (score 0):

My friend helped me with this. You should open MAMP properties/Security end 'Edit' permissions and let modify and write in MAMP app. [solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyRlE.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).